# jquery validate plugin - ignore not visible inputs, but include hidden inputs with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that changes the inputs displayed on screen depending on a drop down list value.

This ignore definition works fine and does not validate any inputs with **ignore** class and that are **not visible**.

```
ignore: ":not(:visible), .ignore",
```

But the problem now is when I want to validate a few `hidden` inputs with class '**validate**' , so I changed this to:

```
ignore: ":hidden:not(.validate), :not(:visible), .ignore",
```

But the **:not(:visible)** blocks it. How to apply these 2 rules together so I will be able to ignore not visible inputs and validate hidden inputs with **'validate'** class?

Comment: FYI - "not visible" means "hidden", which includes, `type="hidden"`, `display:none` and most other common techniques that hide the element from view.  I'm making this point because the plugin already ignores these things by default using `:hidden`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore all hidden elements, but still validate any hidden element with the `.validate` class, it's simply the default `:hidden` selector with the `.validate` class excluded...

```
ignore: ":hidden:not(.validate)"
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/0avft8ou/](http://jsfiddle.net/0avft8ou/)

You probably don't need an `.ignore` class because the plugin will automatically ignore any hidden element.

Comment: I know that sparky, but I want also not to validate all the not visible inputs, I have inputs that their container has a display:none that I don't want to validate them + don't validate hidden inputs unless they have the validate class. Look at what I tried.

Comment: @OffirPe'er, I don't think you tried my demo.  **By default**, the plugin will ignore ALL hidden elements including `display:none`.  See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/0avft8ou/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your first rule as

```
ignore: ":not(:visible), :not(:hidden), .ignore"
```

Comment: I tried this already, I thought maybe it would overwrite it, but it's not.
Also I tried `hidden:not(.validate)!important` but that caused an error.

Comment: as far as I know about jquery.validate , it works (or it can work) on elements based on the names, i.e. we apply validations for individual fields, then why your  validations are being conflicted with each other.??

Comment: Maybe the algorithm that applies to `:not(:visible)` has a conflict with `:not(:hidden)` , you are more then welcome to create a fiddle proving me wrong.

Comment: `:not(:visible)` and `:not(:hidden)` are opposite of each other, and by using both together, you're ignoring EVERYTHING.